# MonoTouch splash fader

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, splash-screen

I'm trying to create a splash screen for MonoTouch, that fades from the Default.png to the application over a short time period.

This is what I have so far in the AppDelegate,

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
    viewController = new App1ViewController ();
    navController = new UINavigationController(viewController);

    UIImageView splash = new UIImageView(window.Bounds);
    splash.Image = UIImage.FromFile("Default.png");
    splash.Alpha = 1.0f;

    window.AddSubview(splash);
    UIView.Animate(5,
    delegate
    {
        splash.Alpha = 0.0f;
    },
    delegate
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Removed.");
        splash.RemoveFromSuperview();
        window.RootViewController = navController;
    });
    window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

    return true;
}
```

But so far it doesn't work/show anything.  Also, is there an event to get the finish of the animation, so I can remove the view?  Is this the right way to go about this?

PS I already have the image files in the root folder of the application and marked as content.  They just don't last long enough on application load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed a few variable names but I hope this helps...

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

        UIImageView splash = new UIImageView(window.Bounds);
        splash.Image = UIImage.FromFile("Default.png");

        var vc = new UIViewController ();
        var nav = new UINavigationController(vc);

        window.AddSubview(splash);
        window.AddSubview(nav.View);
        window.BringSubviewToFront(splash);
        window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

        UIView.Animate(5,
        delegate
        {
            splash.Alpha = 0f;
        },
        delegate
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Removed.");
        window.RootViewController = nav;
            splash.RemoveFromSuperview();

        });

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Please rather use UIImage.FromBundle instead of FromFile so your Default@2x image will be chosen for higher resolution.

Comment: Thanks, should have accepted this answer a while ago.  Its working great.

Comment: I've always used UIImage.FromFile and my @2x file gets loaded.

Answer (score 0):

What is `App.AppFile()`?

You should just be able to use `UIImage.FromFile("Default.png")` if it is in the root of your app.

iOS will also handle the @2x stuff for you.

Comment: App is a utility class I use in all my programs, it has methods that simplify methods - in this case I'm new to MonoTouch and it isn't explained anywhere about root app files.  I'll add to my post the full base class that I'm using, and see if it makes sense - I knew someone would ask...

Comment: Just switch to `UIImage.FromFile("Default.png")`

Comment: Even with `UIImage.FromFile("Default.png")` it still doesn't work.

Comment: It looks like your `navController` might be on top of it, what happens if you remove it and only have the `UIImageView`?

Comment: Two things, it now fades to a black screen - so at least it is working, but it should be fading to the application, and two - get a console error saying `Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch.`  Edited code in main-post to reflect what code currently looks like.

Comment: Thanks for your help, figured it out.  Adding it to the navController instead of the window is the answer.  But I'll have to make a jpg version of it so that the black border around the image stays black instead of going instantly transparent.

Answer (score 0):

call this function from FinishedLaunching hope so your problem get solve by this code

```
public void LaunchSpinner()
{
// launch  spinner for 2 secs
ActivityIndicator objLoadView = new ActivityIndicator ("Please Wait......");
NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer (TimeSpan.FromSeconds (2), () => objLoadView.StopAnimatings ());
}

public class ActivityIndicator : UIActivityIndicatorView
{
UIAlertView _alert;
UIActivityIndicatorView _ai =new UIActivityIndicatorView(); 
public ActivityIndicator()
 {

 }
public ActivityIndicator (String title)
{
_alert = new UIAlertView (title, String.Empty, null, null, null);
_ai = new UIActivityIndicatorView ();
_ai.Frame = new System.Drawing.RectangleF (125, 50, 40, 40);
_ai.ActivityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge;
_alert.AddSubview (_ai);
_ai.StartAnimating ();
_alert.Show (); 
}

public void StopAnimatings ()
{           
_ai.StopAnimating ();
_alert.DismissWithClickedButtonIndex (0, true);
_alert.Hidden = true;
_ai.HidesWhenStopped = true;                    
}
#region IDisposable implementation
void IDisposable.Dispose ()
{
 _alert.DismissWithClickedButtonIndex(0, true);
}
#endregion
}
```